# Upgrading Zend Framework - Steps & Guidance

Tags: php, zend-framework

The site I maintain is currently using Zend Framework 1.8.0, which is over 2 years old. I'd like to upgrade to 1.11.11 and am having some trouble finding basic guidelines for how to pull this off smoothly. Is it as simple as overwriting the library/Zend folder with the latest files?

Here are my steps I plan on taking. Am I missing anything?

1. Download latest Zend Framework code.
2. SSH into the server and copy library/Zend to /path/to/webapp/library and call the folder something like Zend-1.11.
3. Put up "Site is down for maintenance page" on our site.
4. cd /path/to/webapp and then make a backup copy of current Zend version, e.g. cp -R Zend Zend-old
5. mv Zend-1.11 Zend
6. Remove "Site is down for maintenance page"

At this point, the /library/Zend folder would have the latest Zend Framework code and I'd have "Zend-old" to switch back to in case anything goes wrong.

Is this the typical way to upgrade?

Comment: Not sure you have a possibility to update it. ZF doesn't support update if the ZF version is older more than up to 2 releases. I will try to find out the official link to read it.

Comment: Hey Anthony.  I upgraded my local version of ZF from 1.8.0 to 1.11.11 by simply overwriting the library/Zend folder with the latest code.  What do you mean by ZF doesn't support update?  I can't find anything useful re: upgrading on the their site.

Comment: It was described somewhere in the Zend Overview. I remember I could update it from 1.4 to 1.6. But If I had 1.3 I couln't. May be it is possible now. If it possible then you did it correct.

Comment: Ahh, gotcha.  I'm on 1.8 and am trying to go to 1.11 and I haven't seen anything saying I couldn't.  Did you simply overwrite the library/Zend folder to upgrade?

Comment: Yes, like you did it before. Or you can create two folders: Zend-1.8 and Zend-1.11. And in the index.php change inlcude path from /zend/ to /zend-1_11/ for instance.

Answer (score 5):

Things to do before updating Zend Framework:

1. Read the **change log** from your current version to the latest version that you are downloading.
2. While doing so, make sure all your **current code will work** without any bugs, even minor. Usually all updates are backward compatible. (But sometimes, if there are any major changes around a particular module, you will have a little rework in your code)
3. If the new version of ZF has a **new feature** that you can use for your site, modify your site to use it.
4. Update the framework in your **development environment first** (by pointing your lib path to the new framework files) and then make sure all parts of your site works the same and all your tests are passing.
5. Then **update your production site** with the new version using the same way mentioned in the question.

Comment: For point 4 you can of course simply run your unit tests. Can't you?

Comment: Thanks.  I've been reading the change log and have upgraded my local environment and will be doing the dev environment this week to test, test, test!  I'll be using a nifty new feature, specifically the mobile device detection stuff, very excited for that.  So it sounds like the actual upgrading piece is just a matter of overwriting the library/Zend directory.  Cool!

Answer (score 2):

I went through a much more extreme upgrade going from Zend 0.70 to 1.11 a few months back. What I did was qualify the new library folder with a version number and use the application.ini setting to switch between the 2 for testing.

so

```
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
```

would become

```
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library1.11"
```

I found having both entries and just moving a comment was a lot faster for testing. Good luck with your upgrade!

Answer (score -2):

You might also take a look at the ZF-tool.
It is not only the Zend lib that might be replaced with a newer version.
If you replace the Zend lib you beteer type things like zf show version.