# 1.0.0-rc1 zend framework how to use pagination

Tags: php, zend-framework

Can anyone tell me that how to use pagination in zend framework 1.0.0-rc1.

I used this but not working in this version.

```
$db = Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::getDefaultAdapter();
$select = new Zend_Db_Select($db);
$statement = $select->from('product');
$statement = $statement . "order by id desc";
$results = $db->query($statement);
$rows = $results->fetchAll();
$result = $DB->fetchAll($sql);
$page=$this->_getParam('page',1);
$paginator = Zend_Paginator::factory($rows);
$paginator->setItemCountPerPage(10);
$paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($page);
$this->view->paginator=$paginator;
```

Please help me regarding

Comment: I would suggest to upgrade to a newer 1.x version - you are using a release candidate some things might not work. Beside that there were several (security) updates.

Comment: You can download the package (again) and replace your old zf files (replace all files - don't mix them). It is also a good idea to _search the internet_ - then you might find this stackoverflow article: [Upgrading Zend Framework - Steps & Guidance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8491607/upgrading-zend-framework-steps-guidance)

Comment: @Jost I have updated 1.12 3 still not working

Comment: 1. Is there an error message? 2. Can you post a bit more code please (e.g. your view- and controller-scripts).